# Connect variable in JSON file to c#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I have a JSON file which has a variable that has a link. I want it to reference it in my c# file. I am not exactly sure how i would reference the variable in my C# file

```
"urlinmail":"facebook.com"
```

```
 msg.body = <a href = urlinmail/>
```

Comment: You need to extract the value from the Json. You could use Json.NET to parse the file, or another parser, or do it manually.

Comment: That's not valid html nor valid C# ... You need to do something like `msg.body= string.Format("<a href={0}>LinkText</a>", urlinmail);` or `msg.body= $"<a href={urlinmail}>LinkText</a>";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var example1 = @"{""name"":""John Doe"",""age"":20}";

var JSONObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(example1);

JSONObj["name"]; // equals John Doe
JSONObj["age"]; // equals 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2 simple way:

**First Way**

You can use Newtonsoft which is popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET

```
public class Message
{
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

```
string json = @"{
  'MessageBody': 'This is a test Message.',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
}";
```

And in your class which has the functions you can simply do:

```
Message msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json);
```

And now you can use it like:

```
Console.WriteLine(msg.MessageBody);
```

**Second Way**

For .NET CORE Projects, there is another way to do it,

Go to your `appsettings.json`

There is a Logging data which has to look like this :

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
```

Above that put this line to there:

```
"Data": {
    "urlinmail": "facebook.com"
}
```

Now go to your class and you have to constructor inject for configuration.

```
public class MyClass{

     private IConfiguration _configuration;

     public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration){
         _configuration = configuration;
     }

     public MethodToReachJsonData(){
         var urlinmailFromJson = configuration["Data:urlinmail"];
//Now the variable "urlinmailFromJson" data is dynamically what you've assign from appsettings.json
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a "custom" JSON File. So I have to put another answer,

If you want to configure your own custom json file you have to go to your

`Program.cs`

So your `Program.cs` should look like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

             // custom config file
            .AddJsonFile("customconfig.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
            .Build();

        BuildWebHost(args, configuration).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args, IConfiguration config) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Now for accessing this json file, you have to register it from `Startup.cs`

So you have to create a class matches with your Config File, in this example:

```
public class CustomConfig{
   public string CustomAppSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Now go to your `Startup.cs` and in your `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` below `services.AddMvc()` write:

```
services.Configure<CustomConfig>(Configuration);
```

Now you can access to your configuration file,

Go to your main class(this can be a controller)

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private readonly CustomConfig _customConfig;

    public MyController(IOptions<CustomConfig> options)
    {
        _customConfig = options.Value;
    }

    public string JsonData()
    {
        return _customConfig.CustomAppSettings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you can use this is Razor pages via <p> @Configuration["key"] </p>